# How can I set a custom number format, date format, and time format (in KDE, if that matters), independent of any locale-related database of formats?

Tags: linux, fedora, kde

Under "System Settings" > "Regional Settings" > "Region & Language", there are settings for

- Language
- **Numbers**
- **Time**
- Currency
- Measurements
- Paper Size
- Address
- Name Style
- Phone Numbers

The options for all of those things except "Language" come from some kind of database of formats linked to specific locales and languages.  I was able to find decent options for most things, but I want to change the formats under Numbers and Time to something else entirely, a format not available on the list (or not working as advertised, in the case of date formats!).

I have read the question and answers here, but the amount of hoops to jump through to achieve such a simple customization by going about it that way (hacking the locale format data) is insane.  Surely there is a way to **set completely custom formats unrelated to any preinstalled locale format data**.  That's a cinch to do in Windows, so how is it done here?

Note:  Tagged "KDE", "Linux", and "Fedora" since I don't know if this issue (or the fix for it) is specific to my desktop environment or distribution.